# Programmatically change the location of an unmanaged DLL to import

Tags: c#, pinvoke, unmanaged, dllimport

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to separate managed and unmanaged DLLs in another directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10044511/how-to-separate-managed-and-unmanaged-dlls-in-another-directory)

I am using unmanaged code with my C# managed code.  I have the unmanaged DLL embedded in the executable of the application.  In order to make this work I extract the resource/DLL to a file before I make any calls to the DLLs methods.

```
public static class ResourceExtractor
{
    public static void ExtractResourceToFile(string resourceName, string filename)
    {
        if (!System.IO.File.Exists(filename))
            using (System.IO.Stream s = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream(resourceName))
            using (System.IO.FileStream fs = new System.IO.FileStream(filename, System.IO.FileMode.Create))
            {
                byte[] b = new byte[s.Length];
                s.Read(b, 0, b.Length);
                fs.Write(b, 0, b.Length);
            }
    }
}
```

So that before I make calls to the DLL I make sure to do the following:

```
ResourceExtractor.ExtractResourceToFile("Namespace.dll_name.dll", "dll_name.dll");
```

And to wrap the methods of the unmanaged DLL I have...

```
public class DLLWrapper
{
    public const string dllPath = "dll_name.dll";

    [DllImport(dllPath)]
    public static extern uint functionA();

    [DllImport(dllPath)]
    public static extern uint functionB();

    [DllImport(dllPath)]
    public static extern uint functionC();
}
```

**Now for the question...**

This all works.  What I ***DO NOT*** like is that it creates the DLL sitting next to the executable.  I would much rather create the DLL in a temporary directory and load it from there.  Something like...

```
string tempDLLname = Path.GetTempFileName();
ResourceExtractor.ExtractResourceToFile("Namespace.dll_name.dll", tempDLLname );
DLLWrapper.dllPath = tempDLLname;

...

public class DLLWrapper
{
    public static string dllPath;

    [DllImport(dllPath)]
    public static extern uint functionA();

    [DllImport(dllPath)]
    public static extern uint functionB();

    [DllImport(dllPath)]
    public static extern uint functionC();
}
```

However this does not work because `[DllImport(path)]` requires the path to be a `const`.  So how do you change the location that you want to load the DLL from?  I won't know until runtime.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Before you invoke any calls against the dll you can explicitly use LoadLibrary and pass in the full path that you extracted it to.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684175(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Could you please expand upon this answer?  I reviewed your link but I'm unclear on how to actually implement this in practical terms.

Comment: Immediately after you extract the dll to a temp location, call LoadLibrary with that full path to load it into your processes memory.  As long as the dll *name* matches what you used in your DllImport, subsquent calls to an exported function will be handled by the loadded dll.  The same dll name cannot be loaded twice in memory for the same process.