# VB.net Const - Project location path

Tags: vb.net

I am using a SDK with the SDK one of the parameters calls for a const which is a file path to a DLL. The example that I was given hard codes the file path but I need this to point to the project path so that when I deploy I can deploy it anywhere.

I have tried to use a couple of functions to get the file path of the project but because I need a const I get micorsoft error. "Constant expression is required. "

```
Public Const strLibrary As String = System.IO.Path.Combine(My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath, "\E_BEPSET32.DLL")
```

Is it possible to achieve this or do I have to hard code the value?

Comment: Can you show how strLibrary subsequently used? - Just because the example code uses a const doesn't automatically mean you have to as well, have you tired using a regular string variable?

Comment: Its being used like this: <DllImport(strLibrary, EntryPoint:="EPDM_Open")>

Comment: The first place DllImport looks in is the directory in which it's called from, so if the DLL is in the same dir as your exe just use  `<DllImport("E_BEPSET32.DLL", `

Comment: "deploy it anywhere" is not very sensible, but why DLL Hell burns always has to be learned the hard way.  [Look here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10045135/17034).